# Need help in accessing current user's information from cloud firestore and include the information in my application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

**This is where i want to access and include users logged in user's data from firestore**

```
class CategorySelector extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategorySelectorState createState() => _CategorySelectorState();
}

class _CategorySelectorState extends State<CategorySelector> {

  Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String imageName) async{
    Image image;
    await FireStorageService.loadImage(context,imageName).then((value){
      image = Image.network(value.toString(),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    });
    return image;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 80.0,
            height: 80.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    //color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: Offset(8, 8)
                  )
                ]
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _getImage(context,"Screenshot_2020-12-12-07-27-13-73.png"),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  //if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                    return Container(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      child: snapshot.data,
                    );
                  //}
                },
              ),
              /*child: Image(
                image: AssetImage(user.imageUrl),
              ),*/
          ),),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Welcome,',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),),
              Text('hi',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            width: 80.0,
            height: 80.0,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FireStorageService();
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(BuildContext context, String image) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(image).getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

---

**I created this class for user authentication**

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //user registration with email and password
  Future<User> createNewUser(String email, String password, String imageUrl) async {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      User user = result.user;
      print('auth ser $imageUrl');
      if(user != null) {
        await DatabaseManager().createUserData(user.email, imageUrl, user.uid);
        return user;
      }
      return null;
    }catch(e){
      return null;
    }
  }

  //user sign in with email and password
  Future loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return result.user;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }





*//i think this function will help me to access current user's information, but it did not help*
  Future<User> getCurrentUser()async{
    User user =  _auth.currentUser;
    return user;
  }
}
```

---

**this is where i included all database operations.**

```
class DatabaseManager {
  final CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<void> createUserData( String email,String imageUrl, String uid) async{
    return await users.doc(uid).set({
      'id': uid,
      'email': email,
      'user_name': email.substring(0,email.lastIndexOf("@")),
      'img_url': imageUrl
    });
  }
}
```

---

**this is my user model**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class User {
   int id;
   String name;
   String email;
   String imageUrl;
   String password;

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    @required this.email,
    @required this.password,
  });

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    this.id = json['id'];
    this.name = json['name'];
    this.imageUrl = json['img_url'];
    this.email = json['email'];
    this.password = json['password'];

  }
}
```

i really don't know how to retrieve the logged in user's information from firebase. **I want to access the image stored in firebase storage and user's name from firestore and display in my app through class categorySelector.** Help will be appreciated a lot.  This is how i have structured the users collection.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firebase Auth you can access simple data like name, email, and phone number, etc, you can use

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
```

else if you want to access the data in Firestore I suggest you read the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview) and learn it yourself instead of getting a one-time code of how to do it.